# How to Format Turn Floating Point into Exponent Using Constants in C

Tags: c, masking, exponent

So I'm given

```
const int mask = 0x7F800000
const int shift = 23
const int bias = 127

int exp (float number)  {
   unsigned int u = *(unsigned int*)&number;
   int field = 0;
```

Honestly, I'm just confused how to format properly to get what I want. Essentially, client inputs a float and then u is the unsigned int that has the same bit pattern as the float.

I know I need to first mask everything except the exponent variables in a number. So I'd assume it's

```
field = (u & mask)
```

That should presumably mask the bit pattern except for the part we want - the exponent.

Then step two would be to shift it by 23, so its not surrounded by all the zeros...this is where I get confused.

```
field = (u & mask) >> shift ???
```

See, I'm kind of lost. Maybe that's right. We are shifting by 23 to the right regardless.

Then what's last is to take the bias into account. You want to return the actual exponent, not the bits. And the formula to do that is exponent bits = (exp bit pattern) - bias...So then I try this

```
field = ((u & mask) >> shift) - bias;
return(field);
```

And I just can't get the right answer. Firstly, please go easy on my formatting. I'm new to C and this is a beginner project. I know it's not good as is. But, can someone assist me in understanding the formatting to make these steps work? Or help with what I'm missing? I'm just looking for assistance on logic.

Comment: Masking, shifting, and subtracting is correct, and many C implementations will tolerate the aliasing even if the C standard does not define it, although there are better ways. So there is likely some other cause that “I just can't get the right answer.” Edit your question to show a [mre], including a complete program, sample input, observed output, and desired output. Just saying “I just can't get the right answer” is not an adequate problem description. Show a specific case with a wrong answer that the program produces and a right answer.

Comment: I will try to in a little bit. It's part of a larger problem, so the issue may be the other ones aren't complete yet. If what I've provided is correct, I'll just keep going and see if the tests are satisfied. If not, I'll post back here. But the tests are simple...like 6 == 6, 12 == 12. I'm new to this so I'm pretty confused, so I apologize

Answer (score 1):

Three methods:

1. Safest

```
int exp (float number)  {
   unsigned int u;
   memcpy(&u, &numberm sizeof(u));
```

2. Safe in C

```
int exp (float number)  {
   union 
   {
       unsigned int u;
       float f;
   }fu = {.f = number};
```

then you can use `fu.u`

3. Unsafe (pointer puning)

```
int exp (float number)  {
   unsigned int *u = (void *)&number;
```

Having unsigned value `u`

you can for example:

```
#define SIGN (1U << 31)
#define EXP  (0xff << 23)

unsigned sign = !!(u & SIGN)
unsigned exp = (u & EXP) >> 23;
unsigned mant = u & ~(SIGN | EXP);
```

Comment: I appreciate this. However, it is a textbook question I am doing for review in a beginner C course. I need this to be done with what I've provided and <stdlib.h>, <stdio.h> and <float.h> as resources. The given really can't be altered. Can you please take another look?

Comment: @user14452102 I do not use any libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Beware of endianness issues - for an IEEE-754-like layout, we can have the following:

```
     A        A+1      A+2      A+3        Big-endian addressing
    +--------+--------+--------+--------+
    |seeeeeee|efffffff|ffffffff|ffffffff|
    +--------+--------+--------+--------+
     A+3      A+2      A+1      A          Little-endian addressing
```

So on a little-endian system like x86, your value will be formatted as

```
+--------+--------+-------+--------+
|ffffffff|ffffffff|effffff|seeeeeee|
+--------+--------+-------+--------+
```

where the first byte will be the lowest 8 bits of the significand, followed by the middle 8 bits of the significand, followed by the lowest exponent bit, followed by the high 7 bits of the significand, followed by the sign bit, followed by the high 7 bits of the exponent.

Also, there is no guarantee that the bit pattern of a `float` value will fit in an `unsigned int`<sup>1</sup>.  It's better to treat the float value as an array of `unsigned char`:

```
union f32 {
  float f;
  unsigned char c[sizeof f];
};
```

You can assign your value to the `f` member:

```
union f32 myval = {.f = 1.234};
```

and then examine it via the `c` member:

```
printf( "sign bit is %d\n", (f32.c[3] & 0x80) >> 7 );
```

---

1. An `unsigned int` is only required to store values in *at least* the range `[0..65535]`, meaning it can be as little as 16 bits wide; on almost any system built after 2000 it will be 32 bits wide, but it's not something you can count on being universally true.

Comment: "almost any system built after 2000 it will be 32 bits wide, " --> 10s-100s of million per year of embedded processors use 16-bit `int/unsigned` these days.

Comment: I hate to ask, but could you please look again with the provided format and libraries? This is really a simpler question I believe. I mostly want to format the given to return the actual exponent at the end. It's basically (1) mask given field, (2) shift for formatting, (3) use formula exp bits  = exp bit pattern - 1 to result in the exponent.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: Point.  I don't do embedded work, so I never think about it.

Comment: @user14452102: I had to write some code to make sure.  If you decompose the float to an array of `unsigned char` as in my example above, then the exponent bits are not contiguous and you have to use 2 separate masks.  **HOWEVER**, if you save the value to a `uint32_t` (*not `unsigned int`!*), then yes, all you need to do is mask against `0x7f800000`, shift right 23 places, and subtract 127.  **AT LEAST ON MY SYSTEM**.  I can't guarantee this will work everywhere all the time.

Comment: @chux - 8bit ones yes.